# Stripe charge is not working after I move from parse server

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, stripe-payments

I migrated from parse to heroku, and I am using cloud code to handle my stripe charges. I understand that I have to use Stripe library documentation instead of the traditional cloud code syntax. I changed everything but I get this error in the heroku logs. `at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"`

```
Stripe.charges.create({
amount: 100 * 100,
currency: "usd",
customer: request.params.customerId,
card: request.params.cardId
}, function(error, charge) {
if(error){
console.log(error)
}
});
```

Comment: why have you given the space in amount parameter?

Comment: Oh sorry there is a * in between